# Moving files from one directory to another with Java NIO

Tags: java, io, directory, nio

I am using the NIO libraries but I am getting a strange error when I try to move files from one directory to another.

```
String yearNow = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy").format(
    Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

try {
     DirectoryStream<Path> curYearStream = 
       Files.newDirectoryStream(sourceDir, "{" + yearNow + "*}"); 
       //Glob for current year

     Path newDir = Paths.get(sourceDir + "//" + yearNow);

     if (!Files.exists(newDir) || !Files.isDirectory(newDir)) {
         Files.createDirectory(newDir); 
         //create 2014 directory if it doesn't exist
     }
}
```

Iterate over elements that start with "2014" and move them in the new directory (newDir, which is also called 2014)

```
for (Path p : curYearStream) {
    System.out.println(p); //it prints out exactly the files that I need to move
    Files.move(p, newDir); //java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException
}
```

I get the java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException because my folder (2014) already exists. What I actually want to do is move all the files that start with "2014" INSIDE the 2014 directory.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`Files.move`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...%29) is not equivalent to the `mv` command. It won't detect that the destination is a directory and move files into there.

You have to construct the full destination path, file by file. If you want to copy `/src/a.txt` to `/dest/2014/`, the destination path needs to be `/dest/2014/a.txt`.

You may want to do something like this:

```
File srcFile = new File("/src/a.txt");
File destDir = new File("/dest/2014");
Path src = srcFile.toPath();
Path dest = new File(destDir, srcFile.getName()).toPath(); // "/dest/2014/a.txt"
```

Comment: You could do better by using [Paths.get()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html#get-java.lang.String-java.lang.String...-) to create the src and dest, and [Files.move()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...)), setting REPLACE_EXISTING.

Answer (score 18):

Better not going back to java.io.File and using NIO instead:

```
    Path sourceDir = Paths.get("c:\\source");
    Path destinationDir = Paths.get("c:\\dest");

    try (DirectoryStream<Path> directoryStream = Files.newDirectoryStream(sourceDir)) {
        for (Path path : directoryStream) {
            System.out.println("copying " + path.toString());
            Path d2 = destinationDir.resolve(path.getFileName());
            System.out.println("destination File=" + d2);
            Files.move(path, d2, REPLACE_EXISTING);
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Continue with @Andrew's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26622277/13351822)

If we use only `Files.move(src, dst, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);` then it will delete source directory because we only provide a directory path not an absolute path of a particular file. So it will also delete a source directory when operation will be done.

Let's say source path is `/opt/src` which contains a csv files and destination path is `/opt/dst` and I want to move all files from `src` to `dst` and I'm using `Files.move(src, dst, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);` this then it will move all the files to `dst` but it will delete a `src` directory after moving all files because we didn't provide an absolute path of a each file for `src` as well as `dst`. We should have to provide `src` path like `/opt/src/foo.csv` and `dst` path like `/opt/dst/foo.csv` then and then it will not delete a source directory.

`DirectoryStream` used to iterate over the entries in a directory. A directory stream allows for the convenient use of the for-each construct to iterate over a directory. So we get an absolute path for `src` and we use `resolve` method for resolving an absolute path for `dst`.

> Please refer [DirectoryStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/DirectoryStream.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
public class App
{
    public void moveFromSourceToDestination(String sourceName,String destinationName)
    {
        File mydir = new File(sourceName);
        if (mydir.isDirectory())
        {
            File[] myContent = mydir.listFiles();
            for(int i = 0; i < myContent.length; i++)
            {
                File file1 = myContent[i];
                file1.renameTo(new File(destinationName+file1.getName()));
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        App app = new App();
        String sourceName = "C:\\Users\\SourceFolder";
        String destinationName = "C:\\Users\\DestinationFolder\\";
        app.moveFromSourceToDestination(sourceName,destinationName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Using `java.io.File`, its as simple as this:

```
File srcFile = new File(srcDir, fileName);
srcFile.renameTo(new File(destDir, "a.txt"));
```

Comment: java.nio has better file handling than java.io package. I have experienced bad behavior when you dealing with files with special characters in their name. Better way to do things would be the @Andrew's response.